# In interface file: when to use forward declaration for custom class as opposed to just including its header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have subclass of `UIViewController` called `FullScreenViewController` which has a property of type `ImageScrollView` which is subclassed `UIScrollView` object. The implementation and interface look as follows:

**FullScreenViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ImageScrollView;

@interface FullScreenViewController : UIViewController 
{
    ImageScrollView *_scrollView;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) ImageScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

**FullScreenViewController.m**

```
#import "FullScreenViewController.h"
#import "ImageScrollView.h"

@implementation FullScreenViewController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
...
@end
```

now I subclass `FullScreenViewController`, and I try to access any properties from the `ImageScrollView` property and I keep getting the error message: "Property cannot be found". When I add `ImageScrollView.h` to the subclass, it works, but I'm not understanding this. I've already added `ImageScrollView.h` in `FullScreenViewController`, why should I have to add it again?

UPDATE: Rather than using a forward class declaration, I've included ImageScrollView.h in FullScreenViewController.h. I'm a little confused as to why I've ever use a forward declaration versus just including the .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the header:

```
@interface FullScreenViewController : UIViewController 
{
    ImageScrollView *_scrollView;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) ImageScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

a forward declaration `@class ImageScrollView` is all that's needed. This tells the compiler that there is an objc class named `ImageScrollView`.

Of course, with a forward declaration, the interface is not visible where you need to use it unless you also `#import` ImageScrollView where you use it.

> now I subclass FullScreenViewController, and I try to access any properties from the ImageScrollView property and I keep getting the error message: "Property cannot be found". When I add ImageScrollView.h to the subclass, it works, but I'm not understanding this. I've already added ImageScrollView.h in FullScreenViewController, why should I have to add it again?

`ImageScrollView`'s declaration is not visible to the subclass `FullScreenViewControllerSubclass`. `ImageScrollView.h` is visible only where `#import`ed. `FullScreenViewController.m` is not visible to `FullScreenViewControllerSubclass.m`. Therefore, you must write another `#import` in `FullScreenViewControllerSubclass.m` to use `ImageScrollView` there.

> UPDATE: Rather than using a forward class declaration, I've included ImageScrollView.h in FullScreenViewController.h. I'm a little confused as to why I've ever use a forward declaration versus just including the .h file?

Use forwards for fast build times and sane, controlled dependency structures. This is a very time consuming problem to undo. And this problem gets much worse as the size of your programs and libraries increase:

Would you prefer a change to a header in a medium sized project to require recompilation of 50 sources with an average preprocessed input of 150,000 lines per translation, or would you favor that change to affect 6 sources with an average preprocessed input of 40,000 lines per translation? The difference here is that small change takes the incremental rebuild from seconds to minutes to complete, depending on how you have structured your dependencies and imports.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you need to add it is you only have a @class declaration in your FullScreenViewController.h file. That only declares variable of type ImageScrollView* as pointers to object of class ImageScrollView. It does not give you access to the properties of ImageScrollView. To get access to methods and properties specific to ImageScrollView, you need to include the @interface declaration of ImageScrollView, which I assume is in your ImageScrollView.h file.

Comment: Little confused by this. Do you mean to put #import "ImageScrollView.h" in FullScreenViewController.h? If so, when should use forward declaration vs when should import the .h in header?

Comment: If you really meant to use a forward declartion of ImageScrollView in FullScreenViewController.h, then what you are doing right now is fine. To clarify, importing ImageScrollView.h in FullScreenViewController.m is the correct thing to do if you have the above forward declaration and you want to use ImageScrollView properties in FullScreenViewController.m.

Comment: But what about for subclass of FullScreenViewController? What would be the correct approach there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing it using the alias _scrollView or scrollView.you should access it using _scrollView and see if u have imported the file in .m or .h as @class won't suffice.